# Full "Text"-type search alternative/solution for catalog of delimited integers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, delimiter

I am in need of an alternative to the Full Text Catalog/Index for text/character strings, as I am working with integer values. Is there something out there that is faster than using "like" to search through some sort of delimited integer catalog? (Each delimited integer should be indexed throughout the entire catalog, not just that values of each cell as a single unit?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full text search ended up being my solution. I just turned of the integer StopList values so that the integer-only strings could be indexed/searched for.